# laravel sql update isnull with parameters variables

Tags: sql, laravel, isnull

> ```
> $variable = array("apple" , "orange" , null, "apple2");
> DB::statement("UPDATE table1 
>                             SET 
>                             field1= IsNull($variable[0],field1), 
>                             field2= IsNull($variable[2],field2), 
>                     where = someconditional")
> ```

I want if field is null in data array do not update but only that field. other fields (if not null) do it update
How can I write this code in laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$variable = array("apple" , "orange");
DB::table('table1')->where('some_field', $condition)->update(['field1' => $variable[0], 'field2' => $variable[1]]);
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I want
if field is null in data array do not update but only that field. other fields (if not null) do it update.. (I edited the question for it to be more understandable)